# Typescript object with property key set

Tags: typescript, object, generics, properties

I have a Typescript method as follow :

```
function result<T>(query?: Partial<T>): IResult

//Call example
class Test{
  prop1:string,
  prop2:string
}

result<Test>({prop1:"",prop2:""});
```

The method `result` only processes the keys of `query` and does not care about the values.

So would there be a way to have `result` signature changed and have the call looking like follow but still enforce typing:

```
result<Test>({prop1,prop2});
```

I get it is unlikely to be curly brackets but anything that would show that only the properties' keys matter would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

```
function result<T>(query?: Array<keyof T>): IResult
```